# Importing .csv into pandas by fixed start path but changing end path

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following files in a folder:

```
predictions_path = r'C:\Users\Latitude User\OneDrive\Projects\xx\xx\xxx\Predictions\\'

Model_Combined_2010.csv
Model_Combined_2011.csv
Model_Combined_2012.csv
Model_Combined_2013.csv
Model_Combined_2014.csv
```

I would like to get all files that start with `Model_Combined_` which are a `csv`.

I have run the following:

```
csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(predictions_path +'Model_Combined_','*.csv'))

dataframes = []
for csvfile in csvfiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    dataframes.append(df)
allmodels = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
```

But the `dataframes` list is empty. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Check your `csvfiles` variable.  The glob path looks wrong.  It should probably be `glob.glob(os.path.join(predictions_path, 'Model_Combined_*.csv'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have made a mistake in the path!

```
csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(predictions_path, 'Model_Combined_*.csv'))
```

What your current code does is simply concatenate `predictions_path` and `'Model_Combined_'` and then join it with `'*.csv'` using `/` or something else based on the OS. Instead you want to join `predictions_path` and `'Model_Combined_*.csv'`.